# MAMP + NGINX + WordPress = 404 error on sub pages (Permalinks not working)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, mamp

**The Problem**

My local, MAMP powered, installation running WordPress is returning 404 errors on sub pages (the home page / front page work). I know this is because WordPress is looking for Apache's .htaccess file to ensure Permalink rules can be set, but since I've configured MAMP to use NGinx so htaccess isn't used and NGinx doesn't have the configuration to support Permalinks.

However, my attempts to edit NGinx's configuration file to support WordPress Permalinks isn't working.

I think my syntax is just wrong, but I'm not experienced with NGinx configuration files enough to know.

**My Environment**

I am running macOS Sierra (10.12) and also tested on another Mac running macOS Mojave (10.14). Both are using the current version of MAMP (free) with NGinx as the web server enabled.

Here is my default [/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/ccdd3341e5fce8d9a4b21a98ef925204) file.

**Researched Solutions (Which Haven't Worked)**

- I have read numerous posts on StackOverflow (and other sources) but none seem to work or be entirely relevant for my environment.
- I have read [the official WordPress documentation on Permalinks and NGinx](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) on the subject, but it's really dense so I found it hard to locate what is relevant and understand all of the concepts.
- And, of course, [the official MAMP documentation](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/General/SetupWPwithNginx/). Although this is for MAMP Pro and I copied this value into one of the configuration files I test.

**Attempted Solutions (Which Haven't Worked)**

Here are three cases I tried "try files":

- "[line 145 to 147](https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/14ba451488b7c10003b108a50802717a)"

And [here](https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/9b62ceedad8fb97e041e768fef5c94f8) is one where I tried the default WordPress configuration.

Comment: If your syntax is wrong, there will be an error in the error log when you attempt to start/restart Nginx. You can also check the configuration for errors using `nginx -t`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but it reports that NGinx isn't installed. I'm assuming this is because MAMP isolates it from the rest of the system somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I just follow the Nginx documentation for [WordPress](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/). Your solution is almost correct but misses this directive `index index.php;` in server block.

And it might be better to comment the original directives [line 31 to 33](https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/9b62ceedad8fb97e041e768fef5c94f8?L31,33#file-gistfile1-txt-L31-L33).

```
# for readable omitting other directives.

server {
  index index.php;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```